# How to make "say" command speak AND output to the file at the same time

Tags: command-line

When using the `say` command I can give it an option `-o (file name)` for it to record to a file. However, that suppresses the audio output.

Is there a way to make it do both in one command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears difficult or impossible with the built-in `say` command.

You may be able to redirect the audio from `say` into a listening [AUNetSend](http://weblog.rogueamoeba.com/2005/05/19/) that in turn writes to disk and plays the audio; see Audio Hijack below.

## espeak and ffplay

You can use the open source [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/index.html) and [`ffplay`](http://ffmpeg.org) tools to achieve this. The following command both says "Hello world" and creates a `.wav` file of the recording:

```
espeak --stdout "hello world" | tee -a hello.wav | ffplay -i -
```

The command combines three tools:

- `espeak` converts the text into audio.
- `tee` is used to divert a copy of `stdout` to a file.
- `ffplay` plays the audio.

`espeak` can read from a file or web page using the `f` flag:

```
espeak --stdout -f myfile.txt | tee -a myfile.wav | ffplay -i -
```

Another tool such as `ffmpeg` or iTunes can be used to convert the `wav` file to an MP3 or AAC file.

### Install

To install espeak and ffplay, use [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org). With HomeBrew set up, the install command is:

```
brew install espeak ffmpeg
```

## Audio Hijack

Alternatively, a good option is to use a third party tool like [Audio Hijack](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/):

> Record any audio, with Audio Hijack! Save audio from applications like iTunes, Skype or Safari, or from hardware devices like microphones and mixers.

This screen shot shows Audio Hijack taking output from Skype, recording to disk and playing back through the speaker.

[image: Audio Hijack splitting audio]

Comment: Thanks for the great extensive answer! I'm trying to do something very specific with the say command though.

Comment: Then Audio Hijack and routing through the `AUNetSend` module is likely your best option. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

In one command with the built-in `say` command, no; in two built-in commands (`say` and `afplay`), yes:

```
$ say -o /tmp/output-file.aiff Hello
$ afplay /tmp/output-file.aiff
```

In my example, this introduces a very small delay:

```
$ time sh -c "say Hello" 

real    0m0.778s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.012s

$ time sh -c "say -o /tmp/output-file.aiff Hello && afplay /tmp/output-file.aiff"

real    0m1.048s
user    0m0.050s
sys 0m0.048s
```

Comment: @redFur, be advised that I've had problems with "say -o":

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338792/how-can-i-run-say-output-file-without-it-hanging-and-worse-with-more-than